# Swift: How to check if an object is being released

Tags: swift, memory-management, reference-counting

I'm developing a small *weak* datastructures framework. 
A collection of weakely wrapped object has a `remove()` method. 
Inside the method i will delete an object if present and eventually purge the wrappers containing nil references.

The problem raise in the case the `weakCollection.remove(object)` is called inside a `object.deinit()` (may happen indirectly).

In this case (since i need to make a copy for comparison reasons) i will have a SIGABORT due to trying to reference an object that is being deallocated and this is forbidden in swift.

> Cannot form weak reference to instance (0x608000199710) of class
>   XXX. It is possible that this object was
>   over-released, or is in the process of deallocation.

Normally i'd just document it, throw an error or a warning and skip. But i'd like to be safe about this and only remove an object when is not in "releasing" state.
One way would be reading the `referenceCount`, but in swift is not a good idea. Most other reflection/meta techniques i can think of are too expensive.

Plus: Another thing i'd really appreciate to know is if there is any notification/kno/observer i can connect to in order to be notified when object is being released.

Comment: As a workaround i am using NSHashTable
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nshashtable
But that doesn't answer the questions above.